# Get edit form from a webform submission

Tags: webforms, forms

I want to get the edit form from a Webform Submission to handle this in the logged in user area.

Like `node/{node_id}/submission/{submission_id}/edit`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, 
you should click **"Use the administration theme when editing or creating content"** in ***admin/appearance***

Even better, try Administration theme module which will allows you to use you Administration theme on more pages like:

```
node/*/webform-results
node/*/webform-results/*
```

Comment: no, i want to get the submission edit form on site theme. so that the user can edit after logged in